# Optionally split spark dataframe string col into multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have a column in a data set which has the following format:

```
'XX4H30M'
```

I need to extract the numbers in these sequences into two columns ('H', and 'M).

If the format is exactly as described, the following (in pandas) does what I need:

```
d3 = df.colname.str.extract('([0-9])([0-9])', expand=True)
d3.columns = ['H', 'M']
df = pd.concat([df, d3])
```

However, a good number of the cells in this series just contain

```
'XX45M'
 XX3H
```

Is there a way to optionally extract these patterns to insert them into the global df?

For a concrete set of examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['XX1H30M', 'XX45M', 'XX2H'])
```

would end up as

```
Out: 
A  H  M
0  XX1H30M  1  30
1  XX45M  0  45
2  XX2H  2  0
```

What I need can be achieved in pandas with

```
df = df.assign(H=recipes.col.str.extract('([0-9]+)H', expand=False),
      M=recipes.col.str.extract('([0-9]+)M', expand=False)).fillna(0)
```

You can split a column, and add new ones in pyspark with:

```
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['col'], '-')
df = df.withColumn('H', split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('M', split_col.getItem(1))
```

How do I extend this to the case I have (i.e. patterns like 'XX2H45M' with two columns?

Comment: Any idea how to get multiple items back. For example, if I wanted to get items 0 & 1 back in an example that had 3 total items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyspark you can use `regexp_extract`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'A': ['XX1H30M', 'XX45M', 'XX2H']}))

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.withColumn("H", psf.regexp_extract("A", "([0-9]+)H", 1))\
    .withColumn("M", psf.regexp_extract("A", "([0-9]+)M", 1))\
    .show()

    +-------+---+---+
    |      A|  H|  M|
    +-------+---+---+
    |XX1H30M|  1| 30|
    |  XX45M|   | 45|
    |   XX2H|  2|   |
    +-------+---+---+
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine - it keeps everything nicely in pyspark!

Answer (score 0):

I've just turned the pyspark RDD into a pandas dataframe with 'toPandas' and used the pandas command:

```
df = df.assign(H=recipes.col.str.extract('([0-9]+)H', expand=False),
  M=recipes.col.str.extract('([0-9]+)M', expand=False)).fillna(0)
```